# Glade GDK buttons have awful top border

Tags: python, linux, gtk, glade, gdk

Buttons that i have created in drag & drop glade window have some awful top border/outline just [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5tYmE.png)

I Tried to set border relief to [none](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BHWm5.png) and setting [border](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E7E0b.png) in style.css but nothing seems to work.

I would appreciate help, thanks!